# can't 'delete' in Ruby Sequel

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel

I'm starting with the Sequel database library for Ruby.

Given the following code:

```
require 'sequel'
db = Sequel.connect('sqlite://users.db')
users = db[:users]
users.first.delete
```

Ruby throws the error:

```
'delete' : wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

I can delete multiple records, but `.first.delete` doesn't work.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`db[:users]`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-5B-5D) gives you an `Sequel::SQLite::Dataset`. [`users.first`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-first) method *without any argument* gives you a user as `Hash` object. Now you are calling [`Hash#delete`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete), which required a argument. But you are not passing it that argument. Thus it is *complaining*.

Rather do as below :

```
# if you want to delete the the first matching argument of any specific
# attribute/db column
db[:users].filter(:key => 1).delete
# or if you want to delete the first record from db
db[:users].limit(1).delete
```

Read this [`#drop`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop) method also.

Comment: `db[:users]` don`t give an array, but a `Sequel::SQLite::Dataset`. `Array.delete` expects also an argument and would give the same error as `Hash`.  But `Sequel::SQLite::Dataset#delete` don't need an argument - thats why it works without `#first`.

Comment: @knut `Sequel::SQLite::Dataset#delete` will delete all the records right?

Comment: Yes for `db[:users].delete` - it will delete all entries in the table. But you could also use something like `db[:users].filter(:key => 1).delete`. Then it deletes only those with :key = 1.  With `db[:users].limit(1).delete` you would delete one entry (The *first*, but I'm not sure if it is the same you get with `first`.)

Comment: @knut I checked the [source code](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-first-21). Your comment is correct. `db[:users].first(1)` means `db[:users].limit(1).all`.

Comment: You don't want to do `db[:users].limit(1).delete` on any database except MySQL, as the LIMIT clause is only respected for DELETEs on MySQL.  On all other databases you'll end up deleting all rows from the table.